# Error "An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ccxt/-/ccxt-1.63.71.tgz: Request failed 404 Not Found." occurs when running install

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js

I cloned `metaplex(v1.1.1)` and ran `yarn install` and got an error. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.

**Environment**

```
node --version : v16.18.0
yarn --version : 1.22.19
ts-node --version : v10.9.1
```

**Execution command & result**

```
# clone
$ git clone -b v1.1.1 https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex.git ~/metaplex

# install
$ yarn install --cwd ~/metaplex/js

yarn install v1.22.19
[1/5]   Validating package.json...
[2/5]   Resolving packages...
[3/5]   Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ccxt/-/ccxt-1.63.71.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/name/metaplex/js/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Also I get the same error with v1.2.0 of metaplex.

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/ccxt/-/ccxt-1.75.5.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
```

Comment: Why are you trying to clone an old version of the metaplex package?

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this guide](https://docs.metaplex.com/deprecated/candy-machine-js-cli/getting-started#clone-and-install-the-js-cli-repo) and cloned deprecated-clip.git and was able to install without problems.